# How to control the moving and rolling speed after collision in arkit?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, augmented-reality, game-physics, arkit

I have a bullet node and a ball node in arkit,

about bullet, I apply force as below

```
var power: Float = 50
bullet.physicsBody?.applyForce(SCNVector3(orientation.x*power, orientation.y*power, orientation.z*power), asImpulse: true)
```

After the bullet hit the ball, the ball moved to the far away very fast and also rolled very fast,

but if I reduce the power, the bullet moved very slow not like bullet

How to control the ball's moving speed and rolling speed with out changing the bullet applied force.

I checked the document, there are too many parameters, not sure which one works.

```
ball.physicsBody?.(which property I can use?)
```

Thanks

Comment: Hmm...  Restitution?

Comment: doesn't work, I tried  angularDamping and damping, but the initial speed is still very fast, not sure how to control it

Comment: Your question doesn't work, either, since you only show two lines of code.